# Can't find geotools class in jar file/Maven dependency Android app

Tags: java, geotools, android

I am creating an Android app and using an extension from Maven dependency. This extension use geotools classes but when I compile and execute the app I have the following error:

```
020-04-20 21:51:52.743 32378-32378/uca.es.geoprueba E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: uca.es.geoprueba, PID: 32378
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{uca.es.geoprueba/uca.es.geoprueba.MainActivity}: org.wso2.siddhi.core.exception.SiddhiAppCreationException: Error on '93c507cd-f021-434b-8cde-03c49093feb5' @ Line: 1. Position: 233, near 'geo:within(longitude,latitude,"{'type':'Polygon','coordinates':[[[0,0],[0,2],[1,2],[1,0],[0,0]]]}")'.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
 Caused by: org.wso2.siddhi.core.exception.SiddhiAppCreationException: Error on '93c507cd-f021-434b-8cde-03c49093feb5' @ Line: 1. Position: 233, near 'geo:within(longitude,latitude,"{'type':'Polygon','coordinates':[[[0,0],[0,2],[1,2],[1,0],[0,0]]]}")'.
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.executor.function.FunctionExecutor.initExecutor(FunctionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.ExpressionParser.parseExpression(ExpressionParser.java:427)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SelectorParser.getAttributeProcessors(SelectorParser.java:211)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SelectorParser.parse(SelectorParser.java:89)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:115)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SiddhiAppParser.parse(SiddhiAppParser.java:245)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(SiddhiManager.java:65)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(SiddhiManager.java:74)
    at uca.es.geoprueba.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:58)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/geotools/factory/StrictHints;
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory(Unknown Source:0)
    at org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.geo.internal.util.GeometryUtils.<clinit>(GeometryUtils.java:42)
    at org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.geo.internal.util.GeometryUtils.preparedGeometryFromJSON(GeometryUtils.java:75)
    at org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.geo.internal.util.GeoOperation.init(GeoOperation.java:57)
    at org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.geo.function.AbstractGeoOperationExecutor.init(AbstractGeoOperationExecutor.java:47)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.executor.function.FunctionExecutor.initExecutor(FunctionExecutor.java:56)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.ExpressionParser.parseExpression(ExpressionParser.java:427) 
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SelectorParser.getAttributeProcessors(SelectorParser.java:211) 
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SelectorParser.parse(SelectorParser.java:89) 
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:115) 
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SiddhiAppParser.parse(SiddhiAppParser.java:245) 
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(SiddhiManager.java:65) 
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(SiddhiManager.java:74) 
    at uca.es.geoprueba.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:58) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) 
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.geotools.factory.StrictHints
    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory(Unknown Source:0) 
    at org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.geo.internal.util.GeometryUtils.<clinit>(GeometryUtils.java:42) 
    at org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.geo.internal.util.GeometryUtils.preparedGeometryFromJSON(GeometryUtils.java:75) 
    at org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.geo.internal.util.GeoOperation.init(GeoOperation.java:57) 
    at org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.geo.function.AbstractGeoOperationExecutor.init(AbstractGeoOperationExecutor.java:47) 
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.executor.function.FunctionExecutor.initExecutor(FunctionExecutor.java:56) 
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.ExpressionParser.parseExpression(ExpressionParser.java:427) 
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SelectorParser.getAttributeProcessors(SelectorParser.java:211) 
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SelectorParser.parse(SelectorParser.java:89) 
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:115) 
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SiddhiAppParser.parse(SiddhiAppParser.java:245) 
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(SiddhiManager.java:65) 
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(SiddhiManager.java:74) 
    at uca.es.geoprueba.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:58) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/geotools/factory/Hints;
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory(Unknown Source:0) 
    at org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.geo.internal.util.GeometryUtils.<clinit>(GeometryUtils.java:42) 
    at org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.geo.internal.util.GeometryUtils.preparedGeometryFromJSON(GeometryUtils.java:75) 
    at org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.geo.internal.util.GeoOperation.init(GeoOperation.java:57) 
    at org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.geo.function.AbstractGeoOperationExecutor.init(AbstractGeoOperationExecutor.java:47) 
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.executor.function.FunctionExecutor.initExecutor(FunctionExecutor.java:56) 
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.ExpressionParser.parseExpression(ExpressionParser.java:427) 
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SelectorParser.getAttributeProcessors(SelectorParser.java:211) 
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SelectorParser.parse(SelectorParser.java:89) 
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:115) 
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SiddhiAppParser.parse(SiddhiAppParser.java:245) 
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(SiddhiManager.java:65) 
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(SiddhiManager.java:74) 
    at uca.es.geoprueba.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:58) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) 
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.geotools.factory.Hints
    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
```

In project view, I can see that the class is in the jar generated by the Maven dependency.

[image: project view]

For some reason, it doesn't detect the geotools classes. Do yo know why?

Comment: cross-posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61331032/error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-lorg-geotools-factor